# hide linearlayout in bottom of screen while listview scroll

Tags: android, animation, onscroll, onscrolllistener

I have a custom listview and a linear layout with textview at the bottom of the screen. I have implemented a OnScrollListener to hide actionbar and linearlayout while scrolling and bring back once scrolling is done. The Actionbar is hiding smoothly without any flickering and stutter but with the linearlayout its not. I am using animation to hide layout but i am not able to achieve completely. I need the layout should hide like twitter app where the bottom layout hiding smoothly while scroll. Please help.

```
mViews.lists.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (view.getId() == mViews.lists.getId()) {
                final int currentFirstVisibleItem =  mViews.lists.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    if (actionBar != null) {
                        actionBar.hide();
                       mViews.linear.startAnimation(animHide);
                       mViews.linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                    }
                } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
                    actionBar.show();
                 mViews.linear.startAnimation(animShow);
                    mViews.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                }

                mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
            }
        }
    });
```

hide and show xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){

             //Paste here the code for hiding the layout

            }else{

             //Paste here the code for showing the layout

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
  });
```